# Can I use Ionic Push Notifications Channel for Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, push-notification

I'm trying to install [Ionic Push Notifications Channel for Laravel](https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/ionic-push-notifications) package in Laravel 5.2 project using :

```
composer require laravel-notification-channels/ionic-push-notifications
```

as it's in the [package documentation](https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/ionic-push-notifications)

but it seems like this package isn't compatible with Laravel 5.2

I tried also to install an old version using :

```
 composer require laravel-notification-channels/ionic-push-notifications 1.0.0
```

but also it results in these errors :

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
[275.5MB/1227.19s] 
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel-notification-channels/ionic-push-notifications 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by laravel-notification-channels/ionic-push-notifications[1.0.0].

- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.2.45
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
- laravel-notification-channels/ionic-push-notifications 1.0.0 requires illuminate/notifications 5.3.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/notifications[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
- illuminate/notifications v5.3.0 requires illuminate/bus 5.3.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/bus[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
- illuminate/notifications v5.3.16 requires illuminate/bus 5.3.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/bus[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
- illuminate/notifications v5.3.23 requires illuminate/bus 5.3.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/bus[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
- illuminate/notifications v5.3.4 requires illuminate/bus 5.3.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/bus[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
- don't install illuminate/bus v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
- don't install illuminate/bus v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
- don't install illuminate/bus v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
- don't install illuminate/bus v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.2.45, required as 5.2.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.45].
```

So, is there any version to install with Laravel 5.2 or have I to upgrade to Laravel 5.3 to use this package ??

Comment: It requires `"illuminate/notifications": "5.3.*|5.4.*"`, So YES!

Answer (score 0):

You have to install

composer require laravel-notification-channels/ionic-push-notifications

Setting up the Ionic Push service

Add your Ionic Push Authentication Token to your config/services.php

Now you can use the channel in your via() method inside the notification:

You can easily set different settings for iOS and Android individually

In order to let your Notification know which device token to send to, add the routeNotificationForIonicPush method to your Notifiable model.

For details see this link :

https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/ionic-push-notifications